# Cumming's ESCI calculator for within-subjects Cohen's d & 95% CIs

Tags: confidence-interval, degrees-of-freedom, cohens-d

I am calculating Cohen's d and 95% CIs for a within subjects t-test. Cumming's ESCI calculator only estimates the 95% CIs for Cohen's d when df < 200. Is there a theoretical / statistical reason for this limit on the df?

Any guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given the function of the ESCI tool for meta-analysis of *d*, one possibility is that the weighting of effect sizes approaches a limit that doesn't change very much beyond 200 df.  I have not found any mention of this df limit in his book *Understanding The New Statistics*, however.